# Lambda expression and join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using the following linq expression to filter a list:

```
var query =
   follows
      .Where(i => i.EUser.EProviders != null)
      .Join(
         ids,
         i => i.EUser.EProviders.Where(j => j.ProviderType == EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook).First().Ip,
         j => j.Ip,
         (i, j) => i);
```

The query is working but I got a problem in the First() keyword, because I'm comparing only the first element, when I need to compare any provider of type facebook. I'm trying to get all follows that have at least one provider of type facebook and the provider id is contained in the ids.

I think this is working, but I'm not satisfied with the query. Looks wrong to me.

```
follows
.Where(i => i.EUser.EProviders != null)
.Where(i => i.EUser.EProviders.Where(j => j.ProviderType == EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook && ids.Select(k => k.Ip).Contains(j.Ip)).Count() > 0);
```

Comment: Can you explain what result you want to get with this query, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also not that clear, but seems that you want the list of followers of a certain Provider Type contained in a given ip list.

```
var ids = ids.Select(m => m.Ip).ToList();

var query = follows.Where(i => i.EUser.EProviders.Any(m => m.ProviderType ==EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook && ids.Contains(m.Ip)));
```

Comment: look at edit, if you want that at least one EProvider element from Eproviders has a Facebook ProviderType. if that's not what you want... What do you want ?

Comment: Now it's working, you just need to put a parentheses at the end. Thank you. I still can't vote up but I will.

Comment: Great ! No need to upvote, happy to have found a solution : for next time, try to put your code with just a little explanation, as you finally did : just "I still need to check if the Provider of type facebook is contained in the ids" helps a lot !

Comment: Thank you, you are a very nice guy. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want but you may want to use...

```
follows.SelectMany(f=>f.EUser.EProviders.Where(j => j.ProviderType == EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook))
```

or something similar.

If you don't want just 'First' you're using a wrong operator.

Comment: I still need to check if the Provider of type facebook is contained in the ids.